# Visual Studio Bundle for SPA html index page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, bundle

I'm trying to find a way to bundle scripts in Visual Studio. The catch is that I'm using an HTML file and not any ASPX files.

It is a SPA running Angular. The index.html has about 30 JS files I would like to bundle.

I tried using Web Essentials but it appears that that requires you to be running an ASPX page that compiles at run time?

Anyways - it would be nice to do this inside VS, however if I can't then a 3rd party external bundling tool would be fine. Just looking for suggestions on the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you running your website inside IIS though and have .net capabilities?

Comment: The website is running through IIS yes. The website however is all html, other than the API which is the a separate component which is running in asp.net web api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at using Cruncher. [On GitHub](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cruncher/) or download via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cruncher/)

This will allow you to change your JavaScript references to bundle them together into one file.

e.g.

```
<script src="/js.axd?path=jquery-2.0.3.js|test.js|script.js|etc.js"></script>
```

Or you can actually process the files to produce a static minified/bundled version of the files you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check my project. This takes it a step further and bundles everything into a single HTML page.
http://typedlogic.com/SPABundler/